# TypeError: function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo

def function(x,y):
    return (np.sin(x*y+y)*np.exp(-1*(x**2+y**2)))**-1


xi=[0,0]    
answer=spo.fmin(function,xi)
print 'the answer is', answer
```

I am trying to minimise this function. However running it brings up

```
TypeError: function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scipy.optimize.fmin(func, x0, args=(), xtol=0.0001, ftol=0.0001, maxiter=None, maxfun=None, full_output=0, disp=1, retall=0, callback=None)
```

parameter **func** is callable `func(x,*args)`

In this case `fmin` call `function` with one parameter - `x` (which is `xi`). The second parameter must be passed as `args` parameter.

```
xi = 0
args = (0,)
answer = spo.fmin(function, x0=xi, args=args)
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html

Answer (score 1):

Is your intent to minimize over 2 variables ('x','y'), or over just one (with 'y' as an extra parameter)?

```
def fn1(x, y):
    # x is minimization variable
    # y is extra argument
    return (np.sin(x*y+y)*np.exp(-1*(x**2+y**2)))**-1

def fn2(xy):
    # xy is minimization variable; assumed to be 2 elements
    x,y = xy                                             
    return (np.sin(x*y+y)*np.exp(-1*(x**2+y**2)))**-1
```

`fmin` with 1 variable; fails

```
In [35]: optimize.fmin(fn1, x0=0, args=(0,))
Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.
Out[35]: array([ 0.])
```

`fmin` with 2 element array (`x0` and function); returns 2 element array.

```
In [38]: optimize.fmin(fn2, x0=np.array([0,0]))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 2.227274
         Iterations: 64
         Function evaluations: 121
Out[38]: array([ 0.29782369,  0.62167083])
```